# R: How to parse a CFDi XML document

Tags: r, xml, xml-parsing

I'm just starting with R. I´m trying to parse a CFDi XML document. CFDi is a mexican standard for electronic invoices. I´ve tried the XML library normal parsing process with no success:

```
library(XML)
xmlurl <- "CFDi.xml"
xmlfile <- xmlTreeParse(xmlurl)
xmltop <- xmlRoot(xmlfile)
xmltable <- xmlSApply(xmltop, function(x) xmlSApply(x, xmlValue))
```

My xmltable ends up being a Value list rather than a Data matrix:

```
$Emisor
$Emisor$DomicilioFiscal
character(0)

$Emisor$ExpedidoEn
character(0)

$Emisor$RegimenFiscal
character(0)


$Receptor
$Receptor$Domicilio
character(0)


$Conceptos
$Conceptos$Concepto
character(0)

$Conceptos$Concepto
character(0)

$Conceptos$Concepto
character(0)

$Conceptos$Concepto
character(0)

$Conceptos$Concepto
character(0)

$Conceptos$Concepto
character(0)

$Conceptos$Concepto
character(0)

$Conceptos$Concepto
character(0)

$Conceptos$Concepto
character(0)


$Impuestos
Traslados 
       "" 

$Complemento
$Complemento$TimbreFiscalDigital
character(0)
```

I guess my error is related to the schema of the XML but not sure. Here's the CFDi.xml file (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2736898/CFDi.xml). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct but it does not work in this case because the XML file you provided does not have values to extracts.

Tags of your file do not have values inside them but only attributes that is why with `xmlValue` no values are returned.

Furthermore tag names are a little bit tricky because they have a colon inside it.

Here there are some examples:

The last liste of this cose allows you to see the tag names.

```
 xmlfile <- xmlTreeParse(xmlurl, useInternalNodes = T)
 xmltop <- xmlRoot(xmlfile)
 names_file <- xmlSApply(xmltop, xmlName, full = TRUE)
 names_file
            Emisor           Receptor          Conceptos          Impuestos 
     "cfdi:Emisor"    "cfdi:Receptor"   "cfdi:Conceptos"   "cfdi:Impuestos" 
       Complemento 
"cfdi:Complemento"
```

Suppose we want to extract all values (of the attributes) of the cfdi:Impuestos:

```
 xml_impuest <- xpathApply(xmltop, "cfdi:Impuestos", xmlAttrs)
 xml_impuest
[[1]]
totalImpuestosTrasladados 
             "207.440000"
```

Ad you can see, "Impuestos" has only one attributes.

It is better that you define well how parse what and "what" has "what" in terms of attributes and write a precise xPath query to investigate your data (by using `xpathApply`).

Comment: Thanks, I think that could work, except I'm not getting the info out of the attribute as you do. I get a: list() out of xml_impuest.

Comment: Are you sure that you typed names of nodes correctly? My code does produce a results.

Answer (score 0):

You can save yourself a ton of work by using a service that makes the CFDIs for you: [www.facturapi.io](https://www.facturapi.io)

Instead of using a service just for "timbrado", you can use Facturapi for generating the whole invoice for nearly the same price.

(Disclaimer: I'm the author of FacturAPI)